# How can I get output from powershell in C# while a command is running?

Tags: c#, powershell, automation

I'm using powershell in C# with system.management.automation and I can access both the output and the error stream sucessfully. For most applications this is great but i'm right now in a situation where I need to get the output of a powershell command while it is running in c# and i'm lost.

I've tried subscribing to outputcollection.DataAdded, i've tried subscribing to the powershell instance verbose stream, but neither of them are getting called when powershell gives an output.

Here's the code I have so far

```
public async Task<string> CMD(string script)
{
    ps = PowerShell.Create();
    string errorMsg = "";
    string output;

    ps.AddScript(script);
    ps.AddCommand("Out-String");

    PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new();
    ps.Streams.Error.DataAdded += (object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e) =>
    { errorMsg = ((PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>)sender)[e.Index].ToString(); };

    IAsyncResult result = ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

    while (!result.IsCompleted)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new();
    foreach (PSObject outputItem in outputCollection)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString());
    }
    output = stringBuilder.ToString();

    //Clears commands added to runspace
    ps.Commands.Clear();
    Debug.WriteLine(output);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
        MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, "Error");
    return output.Trim();
}
```

I've also tried checking the outputcollection in the while loop but it doesn't give me the output until the command is done.

The command i'm trying to use is Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device
To simulate it in C# it would work the same as doing sleep 5;echo test;sleep 5
where I then want the program to display test after 5 seconds not after the full 10 seconds.

EDIT:

When using "Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device" powershell will deliver this output and wait for the user to complete said task. The issue being that I can't display this in C# because my C# code waits for the powershell command to be finished. And outputcollection.DataAdded never seems to be called.

```
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code CDWS27A56 to authenticate.
```

Comment: No that's an old question of mine which doesn't get output in c# while a powershell command is running

Comment: "I've tried subscribing to outputcollection.DataAdded" - this appears to work just fine with your sample script (`sleep 5;echo test;sleep 5`). Can you describe the output `Connect-ExchangeOnline` usually gives if you use it at the command line?

Comment: When using Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device it waits until the user has opened their browser and written in the code received but I can't read and output to the user said code because my code waits till the powershell command is done which it never is.

I've updated the question, also how did you get outputCollection.DataAdded to work? For me it displays the test message only after the full 10 seconds.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Did you really get it to display test after the 5 seconds and not the full 10?

Comment: I simply verified the `DataAdded` event was raised after only 5 seconds, I didn't attempt to implement a UI - leading me to suspect this is not actually a problem with PowerShell, but with your UI. Can you supply _any_ details about the host application? Is is WPF/Forms? A console app? Where do you intend to write/render the output?

Comment: I'm using WPF as the UI for now

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Connect-ExchangeOnline` is meant only for interactive console use, and specifically gets around allowing the output to be captured (Possibly by writing directly to the `$host` window it was called from?).

Normally, you could try using `Tee-Object` or `Start-Transcript`/`Stop-Transcript` with redirection to dump all output:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath C:\temp\tee.txt -Append
# Then from another process:
Get-Content C:\temp\tee.txt
```

Or try starting a powershell Job, which keeps all of its output in the job object's properties:

```
$job = Start-ThreadJob -Name Connecting -ScriptBlock { Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device }
# Wait for prompt...
$job.Output
$job.Information
```

However, neither of these actually grab the device authentication code.

Currently to use `-Device`, you need to have a visible powershell window and have the user complete their device authentication there.

You can always use one of the other authentication types:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName username@domain.tld
```

This version will automatically launch a Modern Authentication prompt or a browser page. Depending on your use case, it is effectively the same.

Comment: I would love to use something other than the device switch but my issue is that I'm using connect-exchangeonline from a console window where the user can't see the console. And i'm using delegation so I can't use certificates or normal credentials as MFA is required. I can't even disable MFA for my partner account as it is enforced by microsoft when using delegation.

Comment: @Baxorr yeah that sounds like a pain - can you sidestep some of your delegation issues with the `-DelegatedOrganization` flag, or are you using actual user rights delegation?

Comment: I am using the delegated organization flag, it just didn't seem relevant to the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I would pipe the script outputs to a file, then have your c# code read that file, and filter out the code.

Alternatively you could use a class that exposes 2 StringBuilders as properties through which you can use to get the script output and filter out the code:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

public sealed class ProcessOptions
{
    public bool WaitForProcessExit { get; set; }

    public bool Executing { get; internal set; } = true;
}

public class InvokePowershell
{
    public static StringBuilder stdout { get; private set; } = null;
    public static StringBuilder stderr { get; private set; } = null;

    public void string Start(string script)
    {
        var process = new Process();
        var options = new ProcessOptions()
        {
            WaitForProcessExit = true,
        };
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell"; // (or pwsh for powershell core).
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = script;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; // true does not always work so use caution with this.
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        process.Shell(options)
    }

    private static void Shell(this Process process, ProcessOptions options)
    {
        if (stdout is not null && stderr is not null)
        {
            stdout = null;
            stderr = null;
        }

        process.OutputDataReceived += (_, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (stdout is null)
            {
                stdout = new StringBuilder();
            }
            else
            {
                stdout.AppendLine();
            }

            stdout.Append(e.Data);
        };

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (stderr is null)
            {
                stderr = new StringBuilder();
            }
            else
            {
                stderr.AppendLine();
            }

            stderr.Append(e.Data);
        };
        process.Start();
        options.Executing = false;
        if (process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError)
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        if (process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput)
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        if (options.WaitForProcessExit)
            process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

And then you could then make a way to Fire and forget that code (so that way it does not get blocked until powershell exits, then simply in the code you can do the following in your normal code:

```cs
while (InvokePowershell.stdout is null || InvokePowershell.stdout.Length < /* length you expect it to be*/)
{
    // do nothing but by wait by sleeping for a few milliseconds to avoid wasting cpu cycles with this.
}

// strip the code from the stdout property then use it.
```

I find doing something like this is much more cleaner, plus then it could easily be ported to powershell core by changing `powershell` on the Start function to use `pwsh` which is the program name for powershell core and plus then the code would work on all platforms that powershell core supports which are Windows, Mac, and various other linux distributions out there.

Additionally for this to work `powershell` or even `pwsh` if powershell core is wanted to be used instead of `powershell` that the program must be in the PATH environment variable so it can be invoked inside of the terminal directly.

Also with the code above, you could theoretically not Wait for process exit, however I do not know if those events would trigger and populate the StringBuilders then, likewise the process instance would leave scope and be GC'd resulting in the events also getting GC'd and then the StringBuilders never getting assigned to.

As such that is why I recommend calling `InvokePowershell.Start(script);` as a delegate as a fire-and-forget call. Then doing a loop that checks if null or is smaller than the expected length of the string outputs then sleep for a few cpu clockcycles (each clockcycle is less than a second), and then filtering out the results from there after that while loop ensures that it is populated for the preprocessing that comes after the loop.

Edit: Instead of having to call `InvokePowershell.Start(script);` in a fire-and-forget, you can replace the call to `process.WaitForExit()` and the `if` check for it entirely with the while loop shown above, pass in the length you expect to the method, and to the (Shell method by adding it as a parameter to it and remove the options argument, instantiation, and type entirely), and then after the while loop breaks (to allow time for the event handlers to add what you need to the property's stringbuilders, you can call `process.Kill();` to kill powershell or powershell core.

Comment: The powershell function never exits, that's the main problem I've posed in my question. I'm glad you took the time to try and help me though

Comment: That is why I stated it should be called in a fire-and-forget so that way it does not block execution state and you would be able to properly get the results then as well from the properties as the stdout should be assigned the outputs from the powershell script. Or well the parts of it that write to stdout and not stderr. Alternatively you could put the while loop to replace the WaitForExit() call and have it kill (using ``process.Kill()``) powershell after you get all that you need from stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to get the output of a PowerShell command in real time from a C# application.

This uses a PowerShell Pipeline, which allows you to call a notification handler whenever the PowerShell command/script writes output into the Pipeline. I've implemented the solution below as an async enumerable but if you wanted something non-async you can also just use the Pipeline.Output.DataReady handler to trigger some code to read from the pipeline.

https://gist.github.com/OnKey/83cf98e6adafe5a2b4aaf561b138087b

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var script = @"
For ($i=0; $i -le 5; $i++) {
    $i
    Start-Sleep -s 1 
}
";
            var p = new Program();
            await foreach (var item in p.PowerShellAsyncEnumerable(script))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        private IAsyncEnumerable<PSObject> PowerShellAsyncEnumerable(string script)
        {
            var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            rs.Open();
            var pipeline = rs.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);

            return new PsAsyncEnumerable(pipeline);
        }

        internal class PsAsyncEnumerable : IAsyncEnumerable<PSObject>
        {
            private readonly Pipeline pipe;
            public PsAsyncEnumerable(Pipeline pipe) => this.pipe = pipe;

            public IAsyncEnumerator<PSObject> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()) 
                => new PsAsyncEnumerator(this.pipe);
        }

        internal class PsAsyncEnumerator : IAsyncEnumerator<PSObject>
        {
            private readonly Pipeline pipe;
            private TaskCompletionSource dataReady = new();

            public PsAsyncEnumerator(Pipeline pipe)
            {
                this.pipe = pipe;
                this.pipe.Output.DataReady += NotificationHandler;
                this.pipe.Error.DataReady += NotificationHandler;
                this.pipe.InvokeAsync();
            }
            
            private void NotificationHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.dataReady.SetResult();
            }
            
            public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
            {
                this.pipe.Dispose();
                return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
            }

            public async ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync()
            {
                while (!this.pipe.Output.EndOfPipeline)
                {
                    var item = this.pipe.Output.NonBlockingRead(1).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        this.Current = item;
                        return true;
                    }
                
                    await this.dataReady.Task;
                    this.dataReady = new TaskCompletionSource();
                }

                return false;
            }

            public PSObject Current { get; private set; }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
1. In C# Start BackgroundWorker bw;
2. In bw.DoWork(...) Start PowerShell.
3. In PowerShell write to a File and close it.
4. In the Main thread of C# read the File.
===
using System.ComponentModel;
BackgroundWorker bw = new();
bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork; 
private void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    <Start ps>
}
=== in ps
Set obj=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outFile="C:\File.txt"
Set objFile = obj.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write "test string"
objFile.Close # it makes file accessible outside ps
=== In the Main thread
<read the C:\File.txt>
===
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem :/
The issue is that "Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device" waits for the authentication to be completed. Otherwise i'd just use transcribe